# How is this question a dupe?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, exact-duplicates

[$\mathbb{E}[S_n]$, when $S_n$ takes $X_1+...+X_n$ or $Y_1+...+Y_n$?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184380/mathbbes-n-when-s-n-takes-x-1-x-n-or-y-1-y-n)

I don't think it is the same thing as:

[Why does $\mathbb{E}(\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n})=\mathbb{E}(X)$?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184189/why-does-mathbbe-fracx-1-x-nn-mathbbex)

because the former involves conditional expectation.

Comment: I agree it's not a duplicate.  When it was originally posted, it appeared to focus on the question the community identified as a duplicate.  After it was edited, it more clearly focused on iterated expectation. As it stands, it does appear to duplicate other threads about iterated expectations, such as http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69399.  Should we reopen the question and close it as a duplicate of that one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is quite a duplicate.

Of course as soon as you apply the law of total expectation to the 50/50 part the expectation of the components are then each answered by that other question.

[One might argue that it's a duplicate simply by applying linearity of expectation twice, but I think that's perhaps a bit indirect for a duplicate.]